# How to get information of freeze or split columns in excel while reading using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

As i went through apache poi documentation, they say you can get information of freeze or split pane using PanelInformation object in util package. And for that i need object of HSSFSheet class. I am able to get HSSFSHeet object but when I am trying to get PanelInformation from it using getPanelInformation method. It returns me null.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
workbook.setActiveSheet(sheetNumber);
System.out.println(sheet.getPaneInformation());
```

Comment: I have edited my question to explain further. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation here:

**https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html**

The method you are looking for I believe is the method getPaneInformation() which will tell you if the pane you are currently looking at is a freeze or split pane.

Comment: I tried but sheet.getPanelInformation() is returning null.

Comment: Again as per the documentation, that method:

'Returns null if no pane configured, or the pane information.'

Comment: Sorry, the problem was in my code. Now I am able to retrieve the Pane Information and its not null. But How can i get which columns or rows are freeze on that? That is my ultimate requirement. I searched for many methods but not clicking yet.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `null` is normal behavior for [the `getPaneInformation` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getPaneInformation()).

> **Returns:**
>
> null if no pane configured, or the pane information.

This indicates that neither a split pane nor a freeze pane has been set up for your `Sheet`.  If you did create a split pane or a freeze pane, either in the workbook you're reading, or programmatically with `createSplitPane` or `createFreezePane`, then `getPaneInformation` would return a non-`null` `PaneInformation` object.

Comment: Thanks for your help.The problem was in my code. Now I am able to retrieve the Pane Information and its not null. But How can i get which columns or rows are freeze on that? That is my ultimate requirement. I searched for many methods but not clicking yet.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, so I put this information for the sake of sharing Knowledge.

As written previously, you can find out if some rows are frozen with:

```
row.getSheet().getPaneInformation().isFreezePane();
```

Then, you can get the first index of the non-frozen row with:

```
row.getSheet().getPaneInformation().getHorizontalSplitTopRow();
```

According to the Javadoc:

> For a horizontal split returns the top row in the BOTTOM pane.

In case of vertical split, one has to use:

```
 row.getSheet().getVerticalSplitLeftColumn();
```